# Creating "void InsertNode(int a)" and "void DeleteNode(int a)" for Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, insert, linked-list

I'm making a code where I have to insert a node with random numbers and delete each number in order. I'm done with the other functions and I'm trying to code the `void InsertNode(int a)` and `void DeleteNode(int a)`.
And when I run it I get the result below.

> 50 30 20 10 70 80 60 90 100 40
>   50 is inserted
>   30 is inserted
>   20 is inserted
>   ...
>   100 is inserted
>   50 is inserted
>   30 is inserted
>   20 is inserted
>   ...
>   100 is inserted 
>   50 is inserted
>   30 is inserted
>   20 is inserted
>   ...
>   100 is inserted 
>   50 is inserted
>   30 is inserted
>   20 is inserted
>   ...
>   100 is inserted
>   Good Job!

But the result should be like this:

> 50 30 20 10 70 80 60 90 100 40
>   50 is inserted
>   30 is inserted
>   20 is inserted
>   ...
>   100 is inserted
>   10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
>   Good Job!
>   50 is deleted
>   10 20 30 40 60 70 80 90 100
>   30 is deleted
>   10 20 40 60 70 80 90 100
>   20 is deleted
>   10 40 60 70 80 90 100
>   10 is deleted
>   40 60 70 80 90 100
>   70 is deleted
>   40 60 80 90 100
>   80 is deleted
>   40 60 90 100
>   60 is deleted
>   40 90 100
>   90 is deleted
>   40 100
>   100 is deleted
>   40
>   40 is deleted

And this is the whole code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>  
using namespace std;

class Node{
   public:
      int value;
      Node *next;
}; 

class LinkedList{ //Singly Linked List
public:
   LinkedList(){
   head=NULL;
   } 
   void SubMain(){
      bool result;   
      UniqueRandomData(10);
      CallInsertNode();
      PrintNode();
      result=CheckNode();
      CallDeleteNode(); 
   }
   void UniqueRandomData(int n){
      int i, j, k, temp;
      this->n=n;   
      x=new int[n]; 
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)x[i]=(i+1)*10; 
      for(i=0; i<n; i++){
          j=rand()%n;
          k=rand()%n;

          temp=x[j];
          x[j]=x[k];
          x[k]=temp;
      } 

      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
          cout<<x[i]<<" ";
      cout<<endl;
    }
   void InsertNode(int a){
      if (head == NULL) {
          head =  new Node();
      }
      else{
          head->next = new Node();
          head = head->next;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
          cout<<x[i]<<" is inserted."<<endl;
      }
   }
   void PrintNode(){
      Node *cur=head; 
      while(cur!=0){
          cout<<cur->value<<" "; 
          cur=cur->next; 
      } 
      cout<<endl;
   }
   void CallInsertNode(){
      int i;
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)      
         InsertNode(x[i]);   
   }
   bool CheckNode(){
      Node *cur=head;
      while(cur !=NULL && cur->next !=NULL)
      if(cur->value > cur->next->value){
          cout<<"Error!"<<endl;
          cout<<cur->value<<", "<<cur->next->value<<endl;
          return false;
      }
      else 
          cur=cur->next;

      cout<<"Good job!"<<endl;
      return true;
   } 
    void CallDeleteNode(){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){  
            DeleteNode(x[i]); 
            this->PrintNode(); 
        }
    }
     void DeleteNode(int a){
         Node* prev = this->head;
         Node* current = this->head->next;
         while(current->value != a){
             current = current->next;
             prev = prev->next;
         }
         if(current->value == a){
             prev->next = current->next;
             delete current;
         }
         for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
             cout<<x[i]<<" is deleted.";
         }
   }

   private:
       Node *head;
       int *x;
       int n;
}; 

int main(){
    LinkedList x; 
    x.SubMain(); 
    return 0; 
    //system("pause");
}
```

What should I do with the `void InsertNode(int a)` and `void DeleteNode(int a)` function?

Comment: How will you iterate over a single linked list if your `head` actually respresents the tail and `head->next` is never a new node. Also, why check if `head->next` is `NULL` is you never actually set it to `NULL`. Do note pointers and not initialized to `NULL` value.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is a bug here:

```
      head->next = new Node();
      head = head->next;
```

You add a node just after head (thus loosing any nodes that used to be there). Then you move head down one place.

```
      Before Insert is called:

            *********   *********   *********
      head->*  10   *-->*  20   *-->*  50   *--|
            *********   *********   *********

      After Insert(15) is called:

                          head
                            |
                            \/
            *********   *********         *********   *********
            *  10   *-->*   15  *--|      *  20   *-->*  50   *--|
            *********   *********         *********   *********
```

#### Another Bug in DeleteNote()

```
      Before DeleteNode is called:

            *********   *********   *********
      head->*  10   *-->*  20   *-->*  50   *--|
            *********   *********   *********
```

Then a call to DeleteNode(10) will not remove the head item.

#### Another Bug

Your class does not implement the rule of three.

#### Advice

The following members really have nothing to do with a list.

```
   void SubMain(){
   void UniqueRandomData(int n){
   void CallInsertNode(){
    void CallDeleteNode(){

       int *x;
       int n;
```

You should take them out of the class. Free standing function is fine. But if you want you could put them in a test class.

Comment: To add to your answer, maybe it would be good to mention the posibility of using binary search tree, since the dataset obviously needs to be sorted. ( but that's probably overthinking it since this is just a simple exampe )

Comment: Actually all the codes were given and I have to fill in the void InsertNode(int v) and void DeleteNode(int v) so I can't remove any other functions.